Изменение названия переменных и параметров объектов
var test1=12345
var testobj={}
testobj.par1='qwerty'
testobj.par2=function(testing1,testing2){console.log('test')}

При переводе кода через обфускатор, по типу https://obfuscator.io/ код путается, однако имена переменных остаются аналогичными и начав вводить tes в консоли, в самом вверху уже есть переменные test1 и testobj.

То же самое происходит и при минификации через гугловский сервис https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home, в обоих случаях меняются только параметры функции (testing1,testing2), хотя по логике должны меняться все переменные проекта, локальные переменные в функциях (перед которыми стоит var или let), и параметры таких объектов(par1,par2). Подскажите, есть ли в принципе такие сервисы, я нашёл только https://www.npmjs.com/package/minify но проверить то ли это, мне не удалось.

eslint меняет все названия переменных, минифицируя их. Нужно только настроить его. Возможно, webpack тоже умеет такое

@AndreiKhotko, после того как появились присвоения вида let {a, b} = object, имена локальных переменных оказались привязаны к ключам объекта, которые не во власти обфускатора. Не все локальные переменные можно переименовывать без рефакторинга.
